Delayed train Berlin to Amsterdam- evidence
I am looking for evidence for my 5 hour delay on the European Sleeper train from Berlin Hauptbahnhof to Amsterdam (left Berlin on the 20th- and arrived in Amsterdam on the 21st. The journey had delays of 5hours). The rail company have offered a discount on a future journey taken within the next few months, but their own terms and conditions state a 50% refund for 5+ hour delays.

The law says 50% refund starting from 2 hours delay, though there can be exceptions, see https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/rail/index_en.htm#delayed

Even their own site says the same thing https://europeansleeper.freshdesk.com/en/support/solutions/articles/103000118264-my-european-sleeper-train-was-considerably-delayed-en-route-what-am-i-entitled-to-and-what-do-i-nee

What was the reason for the delay?

Are they specifically disputing the delay? Refusing to issue a refund? Or simply not offering it? Could it simply be a case of unclear or disingenuous communication about your options? Rail companies routinely offer alternative compensation, sometimes with a higher face value, in the hopes that passengers will be content with that but it doesn't necessarily mean they won't offer you a refund if you specifically ask.

Thank you for all the replies- I usually document everything so was concerned that I didn’t have evidence of our delay. They have offered my 20% discount on another trip in the next 3 months. I asked for a partial refund and they have sent me a form to fill in.
Thanks again for your replies and time.

You don't usually need to provide evidence.  They can look up the delay in their systems.  In the unlikely event that they deny your compensation request based on the claim that the delay was much shorter or absence, you might have to escalate with evidence; but normally this is not needed.

This site shows that your train arrived with a delay of 302 minutes (5 hours and 2 minutes):

Note that the threshold (by law, and as given on their own website) is 2 hours to get a 50% refund.
However, compensation may not be due in some cases, like exceptional circumstances (extreme weather for instance, people on the tracks, cable theft...). Did they give a reason for the delay?

Amazing! Thank so much. The delays were caused by all sorts of things- but mostly rail works that had run over time I think.
